# Change scrollTop offset when scrolling up, and different offset on scrollDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got an issue, where I have an dynamic header that gets bigger when scrolling up and smaller when scrolling down and therefore needs to change scrollTop offsets.

So i've been looking around and tried with my no existent java skills with no success.

This jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();

    // top position relative to the document
    var pos = $(id).offset().top-500; // move this one

    $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: pos});
});

var iScrollPos = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
        var pos = $(id).offset().top-500; //here when scrolling down
    } else {
        var pos = $(id).offset().top-100; // Here when scrolling up
    }
    iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;
});
```

I made a JS fiddle to show what I'm trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/zq9y7nge/1/

So, Is it possible to change offset depending on scrolling up and down?